# Do not include NaNs in pie chart Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pie-chart

How can I plot a pie chart without including the NaNs that are present in the column of interest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=filter(A2:B, not(iserror(B2:B)))` to omit rows that show NaNs. Then insert a chart that uses the filtered results as its data range.